# cortar texto en un string en jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-maps

Estoy usando la api de google y me trae un ajax con la variable "**adr_address**" y dentro el siguiente dato:

```
"<span class="street-address">Calle 54</span>, 
<span class="extended-address">Mercedes Barrera</span>, 
<span class="locality">Mérida</span>,
<span class="region">Yuc.</span>, <span class="country-name">México</span>"
```

Como se hace para buscar solamente dentro del string:

`<span class="extended-address">Mercedes Barrera</span>`

Y obtener como resultado final "**Mercedes Barrera**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer utilizando la funcion `filter()` de Jquery:

```
$contenido = $('<span class="extended-address">Mercedes Barrera</span>')
console.log($contenido.filter('.extended-address').text());
```

esto mostrará por consola:

```
Mercedes Barrera
```

Comment: me funciona bien, me elimina todas las etiquetas y queda "Calle 54, Mercedes Barrera, Mérida, México". pero me faltaría saber como separar del ajax "<span class="street-address">Calle 54</span>, <span class="extended-address">Mercedes Barrera</span>, <span class="locality">Mérida</span>, <span class="region">Yuc.</span>, <span class="country-name">México</span>" y dejar solo "<span class="extended-address">Mercedes Barrera</span>" :)

Comment: Ok, es el mismo procedimiento, utilizas la funcion **filter()** para recuperar el objeto que deseas, y para recuperar su html puedes utilizar por ejemplo **$contenido.filter('.extended-address').prop('outerHTML');**

Comment: muchas gracias!! si soluciono mi problema. :)

Answer (score 0):

Tomando como referencia la respuesta de ELM. Al contener un string con $() se puede manejar como si fuera un elemento HTML y de ahí aplicar la función de filter.

```js
var jsonResult = '<span class="street-address">Calle 54</span>, <span class="extended-address">Mercedes Barrera</span>, <span class="locality">Mérida</span>, <span class="region">Yuc.</span>, <span class="country-name">México</span>';
console.log($(jsonResult).filter('.extended-address').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: gracias por tu consejo, pero ahora revisando veo un problema en algunas. ejemplo en ocaciones me devuelve esto: `var jsonResult = 'Calle 21, 114, local 5, <span class="street-address">Calle 54</span>, <span class="extended-address">Mercedes Barrera</span>, <span class="locality">Mérida</span>, <span class="region">Yuc.</span>, <span class="country-name">México</span>';
console.log($(jsonResult).filter('.extended-address').text());` y al tener "Calle 21, 114, local 5, " antes me salta un error. hay alguna forma de eliminar todo lo que antecede al <span> ?

Comment: Si te está regresando todos los textos es porque no estás aplicando la funcón de filter. Para obtener todos los contenidos de los spans, debes de agregar el nombre de la clase antenponiendo un punto para que el selector lo reconozca: .filter('.extended-address . street-address .etc').text()

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yxgzLtbo/ hay subí mi ejemplo. si un usuario ingresa una colonia normal. se autocompletara todo bien. pero si ejemplo elige una pizzeria. me agrega una direccion antes de los span y falla mi código :(

Comment: Te va tocar investigar que está retornando según sea cualquier caso. De ahí generar la validación más adecuada. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/?hl=es

Comment: si que mal, por que me gustaría borrar todo el texto que sale antes del <span> en el string. y después ya solo pasar el código que me diste y funcionaria. igual muchas gracias por la ayuda :)